# Web-scraping URL Construction

Tags: python, string, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Consider the URL :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NGC_2808

When I use this directly as my url in `temp = requests.get(url).text` everything works alright.

Now, consider the string `name = NGC2808`. Now, when I do `s = name[:3] + '_' + name[3:]` and then do `url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + s`
,the program doesn't work anymore.

This is code snippet :

```
s = name[:3] + '_' + name[3:]
url0 = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + s

url = requests.get(url0).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(url,"lxml")
soup.prettify()

table = soup.find('table',{'class':'infobox'})
tags = table.find_all('tr')
```

Here is the error:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'`

Edit : 
The name isn't really explicitly defined as `"NGC2808"` but rather comes from scanning a .txt file. But `print(name)` results in `NGC2808`. Now when I provide the name directly, without scanning the file, I get no error. Why is this happening?

Why does this happen?

Comment: Can you please share the error message?

Comment: It's working fine on my machine, I believe the first line of your code(defining the 's' variable)is written at the same indentation level as url0. Now the error you mentioned shows that the HTML parser is unable to find the table tag with class 'infobox', does the result text shown by soup.prettify() contains the <table> you're looking for??? If not then it would be a javascript/angular element load issue or sometimes it happens due to lack of a valid 'user-agent' string which is supposed to be passed in the request headers by the system itself, still you can supply the same manually.

Comment: @AKayNirala The indentation problem came in the question snippet and isn't there in the actual code. How can i supply that manually? And it's not a problem when I define the URL as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NGC_2808

Comment: What is the structure of the text file? Could you provide the code you use for scanning it?

Answer (score 1):

Providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and a copy of the error message would have helped greatly here and may have allowed for greater insight on your issue.

Nevertheless, the following works for me:

```
name = "NGC2808"
s = name[:3] + '_' + name[3:]
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + s
temp = requests.get(url).text
print(temp)
```

---

**Edited due to question changes:**

The error you have provided suggests that beautiful soup has been unable to find any tables in the document returned by your get request. Have you checked the url you are passing to that request and also the content returned?

As it stands I am able to get a list of tags (such as you seem to want) with the following:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

name = "NGC2808"
s = name[:3] + '_' + name[3:]
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + s
temp = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(temp,"lxml")
soup.prettify()

table = soup.find('table',{'class':'infobox'})
tags = table.find_all('tr')
print(tags)
```

The way that the line `s = name[:3] + '_' + name[3:]` is indented is curious and suggests that there is detail missing from the top of your example. It may be useful to have this context, as it could be that whatever logic is involved there is resulting in your passing a malformed url to your get request.

Comment: that indentation is due to a copy paste error and isn't there in the actual code. Also, when I explicitly define the actual URL I get no error

Comment: As for the missing detail,#start
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup are the only things above that snippet

Answer (score 1):

If it only happens when reading from a file source then there must be some special(Unicode) or whitespace characters in your **name** string, if you're using PyCharm then do some debugging or you can simply print the name string(just after reading it from the file) using the **pprint()** or **repr()** method to see that problem causing character, let's take an example code where the normal **print** function won't show the special character but pprint does...

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from pprint import pprint
import requests

# Suppose this is a article id fetched from the file
article_id = "NGC2808   "

# Print will not show any special character
print(article_id)

# Even you can print this special character using repr() method
print(repr(article_id))

# Pprint shows a the character code in place of special character
pprint(article_id)

# Now this code will produce an error
article_id_mod = article_id[:3] + '_' + article_id[3:]
url = 'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/' + article_id_mod

response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"lxml")

table = soup.find('table',{'class':'infobox'})
if table:
    tags = table.find_all('tr')
    print(tags)
```

Now to resolve the same you can do:

- **In case of extra whitespaces at the beginning/ending of the string**: Use **strip()** method

  article_id = article_id.strip()
- **If there are a special character(s)**: Use appropriate **regex** expression or simply open the file using editors like vscode/sublime/notepad++ and utilze the find/replace option.